# search worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have this VBA code, searching sheets name, the code works.

How can I change it to search only partial name?
full name dog, partial name do*, something like this...

```
Dim xName As String
Dim xFound As Boolean

xName = InputBox("הכנס/י שם ספק לחיפוש בקובץ", "Sheet search")

If xName = "" Then Exit Sub

On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(xName).Select
xFound = (Err = 0)
On Error GoTo 0

If xFound Then    
Else
    MsgBox ("הספק " & xName & " לא נמצא")        
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need (and recommended ) to use `On Error Resume Next` in this scenario.

Loop through the worksheets, and compare the worksheet's name with the value you are looking for. You can either use the wild-card `*`, or use `Instr` function.

```
Dim xName As String
Dim xFound As Boolean
Dim Sht As Worksheet

xName = InputBox("הכנס/י שם ספק לחיפוש בקובץ", "Sheet search")

For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Sht.Name Like xName & "*" Then ' sheet name found
        ' do something
        xFound = True ' raise flag

        Exit For
    End If
Next Sht

If xFound = False Then
    MsgBox ("הספק " & xName & " לא נמצא")
End If
```

**Note**: try not to use the Hebrew characters while coding in VBA, it will only give you grief in the future (I stopped that 15 years ago).

---

If you want to use `Instr` function, the use something like the code bellow:

```
If InStr(Sht.Name, xName) > 0 Then  ' <-- Using Instr
```